# download link in html table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Previously I could download files from gridview and code in GridView1_RowCommand

code is

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "cmd")
        {
            string filename = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            string path = MapPath("~/Docfiles/" + filename);
            byte[] bts = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "Application/octet-stream");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bts.Length.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +
            filename);
            Response.BinaryWrite(bts);
            Response.Flush();
```

but now 
I create a table and show some data and I want a download link in table 
here is table code...

```
<div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
            <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
              id="results">
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       Document ID
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        Document Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        File Uploaded
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Document Type
                    </td>

                </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                <%--<td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileUploaded") %>' 
           CommandName="cmd">Download</asp:LinkButton></td>--%>
                <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DocumentID") %></td>

                <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "
                     DocumentName")%> </td>
                <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,
                                "FileUploaded")%></td>
                <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
                      "Document")%></td>
                </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater> 
                <div id="pageNavPosition" >
                </div>              
            </table>
            </div>
```

now how do I add a download link in table and what I write instead of GridView1_RowCommand ????

any solution?

Comment: I am not sure about what you would like to achieve. This may be of help http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Comment: i try to add download button in table...when i click on download files will be download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand, you store files in some folder called "Docfiles". 
All you need to do add hyperlink in ItemTemplate on this file

```
<td><a href="/Docfiles/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentName")%>">Download</a></td>
```

GridView1_RowCommand not needed in this scenario

Comment: but how i code in download button...when i click on daownload flies will be download

Comment: where did you store files?

Comment: in Docfiles..and show in table when user click on download this file will be download

Comment: If you store files in file system on server in folder "Docfiles", you need only generate valid hyperlink on file. Download started then user click on hyperlink

Comment: It is still elegant to make a reference to comments already containing the reference you have used for your answer.